# Configuration of Team City Server

Tags: automation, cucumber, teamcity

Can any one help me out with two configurations in Team City

1. Email Setup with customized options like , Subject , Body and attaching a file while sending the results of build to the users
2. Is there a way to display JSON Reports generated through Cucumber Runner file in Team City ? actually this is present for Jenkins , just wondering if we have similar kind of plugin for Team city too ??

Answer (score 0):

For email customization, look at the TeamCity documentation for explanations on where to update the email templates.   Likely located on the JetBrains doc site under "Cusomization Notifications"(https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Customizing+Notifications)  You'll want to be sure you're looking at the documenation for the version you're running.

For reports, assuming the reports you're trying to display are in HTML format, then yes it is possible, and it is pretty nice.  In high level, you'll have your runner generate the reports, put them into an artifact, then configure TeamCity via the Report Tabs settings in the admin section and that's it!   More info on the JetBrains site under "Including Third Party Reports in the Build Results" ( https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results)  My team uses this for displaying HTML reports from our runner; way better than digging into the artifacts for each build.

Comment: Thanks OCary , For email configuration , i have gone through the documentation , but i couldn't see any such configuration options in UI And for reports ill try with HTML format , actually i was looking for JSON Reports to be displayed.

Comment: If possible can you please guide me, where exactly i could find those options in UI ? for email configuration.

Comment: I want HTML content to be displayed in the body of email while sending and also i could see , email configuration can be done globally , is it possible to have , individual subjects , body's for individual projects ?